# Converting array that holding html elements into NodeList with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td class="some"></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="some"></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
            <td class="some"></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>            
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    //Convert the table to columns
    var columns = [];
    var trs = $("table tr");
    for(i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
        var column = [];
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
            column.push($(trs[j]).find("td")[i]);            
        }
        columns.push(column);
    }
</script>
```

**The Problem**
I can't use $.find method on the array to filter by selector.
For Example, this code won't find anything:

```
<script>
   $(columns[0]).find(".some").length // will print 0
</script>
```

**Question**
How can I trick jQuery engine to assume that columns[0] is NodeList?
I don't want to use cloning because it's not good enough for my project.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the inner `for` loop? What are you expecting of `trs[j][i]`? The `[j]` element will always be one if the first three elements in the jQuery object, and the `[i]` will most likely be `undefined`.

Comment: ...and FYI, a `table` element already provides a 2 dimensional array of nodes. `table.rows` is a collection of `tr` elements, and each `tr` has a `.cells` collection of `td/th` elements.

Comment: I added another tr so it won't fail now. but it's not an answer to my question anyway.

Comment: Your question is based on illogical code as I pointed out in my first comment. I see no sense in fetching the first three `tr` elements over and over again, and asking for an incrementing numeric property on each one.

Comment: @user3692815 Your code has many errors. Anyway, why not `var columns = $('table td');` and then if you are interested in `.some` you can just do `var someColumns = columns.filter('.some');`

Comment: I want my table to be an array of columns and diagonals. So i need to do it manually

Comment: Well, you're assuming that jQuery will receive an Array of Arrays, which according to its documented API, it does not. It doesn't have anything to do with "tricking" it into thinking it's a NodeList. If you need a 2D Array like that, then you need to iterate the outer Array and pass the inner Array to a jQuery object. Or just make an Array of jQuery objects to begin with.

Comment: Ok if i'll iterate over it and get only 2d array. How can i user the $.find method?

Comment: `$(outerArray[i]).find(".some")`

Comment: That's the point that it doesn't work. Try it.

Comment: @user3692815: Yes it does work. If `outerArray` is an Array of Arrays containing nodes, you can pass each individual inner Array to jQuery independently. You can't just pass the entire 2d array. You need to iterate the outer array, and pass each inner Array to jQuery one at a time. That's why it's `$(outerArray[i])` and not `$(outerArray)`

Comment: I Updated my code but it's still not working.

Comment: I need to convert the 2d array to nodelist somehow

Comment: *jQuery doesn't care about node lists. It will receive an Array of nodes without any issues.* You're using `.find()` incorrectly.

Comment: `$(columns[0]).find(".some").length` what incorrect here?

Comment: `columns[0]` is an Array of `td` elements. The `.find()` method searches *descendants* of each element, and a `td` will never have a nested `td` unless there's a nested table. You want `.filter()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. i'll use filter